# The fan on my heat-sink is dead, how do I figure out what to replace?

Tags: fan, heatsink

The fan on my heat-sink died and I need to know how to tell what type of heat-sink it is, if there's anything beyond thermal gel that I should think about?

Comment: Please note that shopping recommendations are off-topic, as stated by the **[FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)**: `Is it not about a shopping or buying recommendation`. If you want your question to stay open, then please correct your question so it asks *how to decide* and not what to buy: [An in-depth explanation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Comment: +1 @Tom Wijsman: Thanks for the link to the blog post by Jeff, that was a huge help. I've edited the question, not so much to get it opened, but just to clean up the question. If you have any additional feedback that'd be great. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fan/heatsink combo is normally designed to fit a certain type of processor architecture.  For example, an Athlon 64 processor may fit a Socket AM2 motherboard, and thus you would need a fan/heatsink combo that is compatible with a Socket AM2 motherboard.  Also, sometimes the socket/slot type is printed on the motherboard.

Most fans are specially made for a certain heatsink, but it not always the case.  As such (and as prices for fan/heatsink combos are relatively cheap) it is best to look for a new fan/heatsink combo.

Be wary of branded PC's and replacement fan/heatsinks.  Sometimes the new features of a fan/heatsink will not work with a branded PC.  I recently had an HP PC that had hardcoded the fan speed minimum into the BIOS--when I tried a new fan/heatsink that didn't need to run as fast the BIOS thought the fan was broken and shut down the PC.  If it's a branded PC I'd get the part number from the Manufacturer and start there.

On that same note, custom PCs are designed to be compatible with a plethora of fan/heatsink combos.

Comment: +1 @Theo: Thanks, finally got to replacing it last night -- it was easy enough. The thermal grease cost more than the fan/heatsink combo; which I didn't know were combo until now. Another thing was that I final got a used some compressed air on the internals of the box, which made a big difference in getting the dust out; before I was only using a vac. Do you have an opinion on thermal grease and/or removing old thermal pads? Cheers!

Comment: I do.  I consider it necessary.  Granted I could mention the properties of silver alloys and how heat dissipation in certain parts of the alloys has a half-life, but there's a better reason...it's cheap!  They sell a 2-part remover/primer for chips that works wonders.

Answer (score 2):

Any heatsink and fan that fits a "Socket A" - the higher spec the better.