# What is a "socket A" heatsink?

Tags: heatsink

Asked a question about replacing a CPU heatsink and it got closed. Before it was closed, got an answer saying to get a SOCKET-A heatsink. Is that all I need to know?

Here's a link to the question that was closed, which has specs on the type of system and heatsink that died(not posting it again, since it appears posting that info got the question closed)
[The fan on my heat-sink is dead, how do I figure out what to replace?](https://superuser.com/questions/266174/fan-on-my-heatsink-is-dead-what-do-i-order)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "socket A heatsink" is a [heatsink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heatsink) that fits on [socket A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_A). That's all you need to know...

I bet you just go to a store and buy a new heatsink for that specific socket. Or if you can put a new fan on it then just disassemble the fan from the heatsink and assemble a new fan on it; fans have standardized sizes.